# VB.NET could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio

The windows app I'm working on crashes when I do certain things in it and gives me the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=6.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name:
>   'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=6.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'    at
>   OpsV3_DAL.OpsV3DB.GetCreditRemittanceOrder(Int32 orderID)    at
>   OPSv3.FormProcessCreditCards.ChecksNew() in
>   C:\Users\janets\Downloads\AmericaFirst_Release1\Contact Manager
>   Lite\Contact Manager Lite\FormProcessCreditCards.vb:line 845    at
>   OPSv3.FormProcessCreditCards.TBPrintChecks_ButtonClick(Object sender,
>   ToolBarButtonClickEventArgs e) in
>   C:\Users\janets\Downloads\AmericaFirst_Release1\Contact Manager
>   Lite\Contact Manager Lite\FormProcessCreditCards.vb:line 799    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolBar.WmReflectCommand(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolBar.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg,
>   IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

I compiled the app in visual studio before and it worked fine.
And then all of a sudden some features started giving me this error.
Does anyone know why I get this error?
This is not an app that I wrote.I took over someone's app they wrote in .NET and I don't have access to the developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a DLL missing. It might be `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll`, but it could also be something else (referred to as "or one of its dependencies"). Such a thing may happen if you switched from Debug build to Release build or various other reasons.

For a root cause analysis, I suggest the following:

Get [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) and record all file activities. Set a filter for your application. After reproducing the problem, save the log as XML file.

Then get my tool [ProcMon Analyzer](http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/procmonanalyzer/) (note: I'm the author of it) and open the XML file. It will analyze it and give a list of DLLs that were not found.

You could also do that manually, but note that some DLLs may not be found at first, but later be found when looking in the `%PATH%` environment variable, the GAC or similar. The tool will remove all those entries which have `PATH NOT FOUND` first but `SUCCESS` later.